# how to display part of the canvas after scaling in html5

Tags: html, canvas, scaling

**How to display part of canvas after scaling in html5**

For ex:

```
var c =document.getElementById("mycanvas");
var canvas = c.getContext("2d");
canvas.scale(4,4);
    canvas.drawImage(img,0,0);
    canvas.drawImage(img,200,200);
```

`img` is some image.

Here i have scaled it some value, now it displays the top-left region of the canvas(with only the top-left image) but what if i want it to display bottom-right region(only the bottom-right image) or according to the coordinates i give to it. How can i do that?

Can someone plz help me on this? I will be very grateful.....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

<strike>If you are scaling you must remember that the coordinates you use to position will also be scaled up, so if you are scaling by a factor of `4` than your coordinates will be `200 * 4` and not `200`. To scale the image alone you can use the call `drawImage(img,x,y,width,height)` and use...</strike>

```
var c = document.getElementById("mycanvas");
var ctx = c.getContext("2d");
var scale = 4;
var width = img.width * scale;
var height = img.height * scale;
ctx.drawImage(img, 0, 0, width, height);
ctx.drawImage(img, 200, 200, width, height);
```

Or you will need to divide your coordinates by the scale factor...

```
var c = document.getElementById("mycanvas");
var ctx = c.getContext("2d");
var scale = 4;
ctx.scale(scale, scale);
ctx.drawImage(img, 0, 0);
ctx.drawImage(img, 200 / scale, 200 / scale);
```

I've put together a fiddle showing the latter approach using clipping to ensure that the image stays in its quadrant http://jsfiddle.net/ujtd2/

**Edit** using the state stack you can prevent having to do the conversion yourself.

```
var c = document.getElementById("mycanvas");
var ctx = c.getContext("2d");
var scale = 4;

// add a new item to the context state stack
ctx.save();
ctx.scale(scale, scale);
ctx.drawImage(img, 0, 0);

// discard the previous state be restoring the last state
// back to normal scale
ctx.restore();

// Set translation
ctx.translate(200, 200);

// Repeat for second image
ctx.save();
ctx.scale(scale, scale);
ctx.drawImage(img, 0, 0);
```

I follow now. To zoom in and show the part of the scene from a specific coordinate use translate.

```
ctx.scale(4, 4);
ctx.translate(-200, -200);
ctx.drawImage(img, 0, 0);
ctx.drawImage(img, 200, 200);
```

This zooms in by 4 and then moves the visible portion down and right by 200 pixels, by translating the drawing coordinates up and left by 200 pixels.

Comment: thnx for kicking in, but what if there r many images on the canvas then i have to go around every image to scale them. isn't thr way to accomplish the same thing(that u did with image) with canvas?

Comment: I'm not quite sure what you intend to do, you'll have to explain it further

Comment: i kinda want to bring slow zooming effect to my animation. let say 2 balls are approaching each other and i want to slowly zoom in (by slowly scaling up after every iteration) when they are about to collide and also consider the background image which needs to be scaled as well.

Answer (score 0):

You can use drawImage the following way :

```
drawImage(
    image,
    sourceX,
    sourceY,
    sourceWidth,
    sourceHeight,
    destinationX,
    destinationY,
    destinationWidth, 
    destinationHeight
 );
```

You determine the region of the source you want and then the place you want to put it on your canvas.

You can find some info here : [MDN Draw image documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Canvas_tutorial/Using_images#Slicing)